# Is there away to see object paths whilst editing objects in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, path

Hey i've been really out of touch with indesign and this is hopefully an easy fix.

I would like to see the actual vector lines highlighted selecting objects.

Currently when I select an object I just see the blue bounding box, and smart guides help me see the vector lines but only when I hover the vector line itself?

Is the away to turn a view on so you can see the vector lines highlighted?

This is what i'm seeing...

[image]

But I would like to see this kind of thing below always (this is smart guides when hovering the vector line not object)

[image]

I know this view is possible in illustrator, but kinda annoying I cant see the paths in indesign.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) In InDesign. It will show paths the same way Illustrator does. (And no bounding box)

Comment: indeed it does, but then lets say i want to grab an anchor and drag the object via the anchor so it snaps to another object, the Direct Selection tool will do what illustrator does and only pull the anchor itself. I think i'm asking to much of ID, i'm guna use illustrator now to create my drawings. Thanks tho dude

Comment: The Direct Selection Tool only pulls an anchor in InDesign as well, if you only click that anchor... Selecting a single anchor is a tad more difficult in InDesign. In InDesign you have to UNselect the path and then ONLY click the anchor,  but it all works the same.